# Need help to track guesses higher or lower HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I was wondering if someone can help point me in the direction to use the .push() function to store a user's guesses in a higher or lower guessing game? And how would I be able to prevent duplicate guesses? I have the for loop commented because it would break my webpage. Thanks for any help!

```
let valid_input = false;
let number, input;

while(!valid_input){
    input = window.prompt("Enter a positive number!");

    number = Number(input);

    if(number != NaN && number > 0){
        valid_input = true;
    }
}

let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * number) + 1;

console.log(num);


function do_guess() {
    let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);

    let message = document.getElementById("message");

    let totalGuess = [];

    /*for(i = 0; guess != num; i++){
        totalGuess.push(i);
    }*/

    if(guess == num) {
        message.innerHTML = `You got it! Good Guess! </br> It took you ${totalGuess.indexOf(guess) + 2} to get it right and your guesses were ${totalGuess}`
        console.log(`It took you ${totalGuess.indexOf(guess) + 1} guesses to get it right...`);
    }

    else if(guess <= 0){
        message.innerHTML = "That number is out of range, try again."//Guess is negative
    }

    else if(guess > number){
        message.innerHTML = "That number is out of range, try again."// Guess is higher than the range of number they inputed
    }

    else if (guess > num) {
        message.innerHTML = "No, you guessed too high. Try a lower number!"// guessed too high
    }

    else if(guess < num){
        message.innerHTML = "No, you guessed too low. Try a higher number!"// Guessed too low
    }

    else{
        message.innerHTML = "Please enter a number!" //Guessed any non number
    }
    console.log(totalGuess);
}
```

Comment: Please help us by posting a minimal example that illustrate the problem.   This helps us focus on the issue, and it gives you a precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Set data structure to store each guess.  Set, unlike Array, ignores duplicate elements:

```
 let totalGuess = new Set();
 ...
 totalGuess.add(guess);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always when there is a valid guess you just can push it to your array

```
totalGuess.push()
```

To check if the value is already in your array you can use *Arrays includes method* in combination with the Logical Not Operator *!*.

When the array is not including the number then push it.

```
if(!totalGuess.includes(SOMENUMBER)){
    totalGuess.push()
}
```

The snippet shows how it works

```js
let valid_input = false;
let number, input;
let totalGuess = [];


while (!valid_input) {
  input = window.prompt("Enter a positive number!");

  number = Number(input);

  if (number != NaN && number > 0) {
    valid_input = true;
  }
}


document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', do_guess)

const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * number) + 1;



function do_guess() {
  let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);

  let message = document.getElementById("message");

  if (guess == num) {
    message.innerHTML = `You got it! Good Guess! </br> It took you ${totalGuess.length+1} to get it right and your guesses were ${totalGuess}`
    console.log(`It took you ${totalGuess.length+ 1} guesses to get it right...`);
    console.log(totalGuess);

    totalGuess = [];

  } else if (guess <= 0) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number is out of range, try again." //Guess is negative
  } else if (guess > number) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number is out of range, try again." // Guess is higher than the range of number they inputed
  } else if (guess > num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, you guessed too high. Try a lower number!" // guessed too high
    if (!totalGuess.includes(guess)) {
      totalGuess.push(guess);
    }

  } else if (guess < num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, you guessed too low. Try a higher number!" // Guessed too low
    if (!totalGuess.includes(guess)) {
      totalGuess.push(guess);
    }
  } else {
    message.innerHTML = "Please enter a number!" //Guessed any non number

  }
}
```

```html
<input id="guess"></input>
<button id="btn">Click</button>

<div id="message"></div>
```